# flash as3 run a function only if instance within function is defined

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, load, undefined

I have a situation where, upon loading my swf, I add an event listener to the stage to listen for keyboard commands. One of them is to listen for the spacebar, and if it is pressed, it should play a movie. The problem is, that movie is not loaded until later on, depending other user interactions, therefore, until it is loaded, the reference to it would be undefined. But if I wait and add the listener for key commands only when the movie is loaded, then I can't utilize the listener for other keyboard commands, like RIGHT or LEFT, which are the buttons which get you to the movie in the first place. Is there a way to add a conditional or something to prevent that code from being executed if the video is not defined yet? Here's my code:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressedDown);

function togglePause(event:MouseEvent):void {
     video.videoPaused = !video.videoPaused; //video is undefined initially so this throws errors.
}

function keyPressedDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
     switch (key) {
        case 32: //Spacebar
        //togglePause();
     }
}

function loadVideo(){ //called based on user interactions which happen later on
    var video:VideoLoader = new VideoLoader(project_array[cp].project_display_files[0], {name:"myVideo", container:this, bgColor:0x000000, autoPlay:false, volume:1,onComplete:vidLoaded});
    video.load(); //currently set up for only one video ([0])-->
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a variable was defined or not just use  `if(typeof myVar == 'undefined')` or `if(myVar === undefined)`.

To check if a variable was defined but wasn't assigned a value use the following:

```
var myVar:MyClass;
if(myVar === null)
    ...
```

Now going to your particular case, having that the `video` variable is declared inside the `loadVideo` function/method, it will never be available outside that scope. So you need to declare it at a higher level to be able to work with it.

Other mistakes:
- in `togglePause` the parameter should be optional to allow for manual calling of the function
- in `keyPressedDown` the variable `key` is not defined

Try this for a change:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressedDown);

var video:VideoLoader;

function togglePause(event:MouseEvent = null):void {
    if(video)
        video.videoPaused = !video.videoPaused; //video is undefined initially so this throws errors.
}

function keyPressedDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
     switch (event.charCode) {
        case 32: //Spacebar
            togglePause();
            break; // not necesary here, but good practice to add it!
     }
}

function loadVideo(){ //called based on user interactions which happen later on
    video = new VideoLoader(project_array[cp].project_display_files[0], {name:"myVideo", container:this, bgColor:0x000000, autoPlay:false, volume:1,onComplete:vidLoaded});
    video.load(); //currently set up for only one video ([0])-->
}
```

*Disclaimer: Not tested, but it will probably work, or at least be close to working.*

Regards,
Alin

Comment: Ah - that's what I was doing wrong - I was declaring the video earlier, but not specifying it as type :VideoLoader, and referencing it later as video:VideoLoader. Once I reversed these two things, it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could throw a try/catch in there to take care of it. Not super efficient, but in this case it wouldn't probably cause any harm:

```
try {
 switch (key) {
    case 32: //Spacebar
    //togglePause();
 }
} catch (e:Error){
    // trace(e.message) // if it's needed, otherwise just fail silently
}
```

Or, you could just define a boolean variable, like:

```
var isLoaded:Boolean = false;
```

then, have a load listener, and when that fires, change isLoaded = true, then:

```
switch (key) {
    case 32: //Spacebar
    if (isLoaded){
      //togglePause();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - the problem was scope, as mentioned above, but the catch / try is a helpful technique to know.

Comment: yeah, works wonders in a pinch. not so optimized though if you start putting it into things that are called a lot over and over (ie: on a timer, or enter_frame) cause the catch has to figure out what it's catching and accomodate for that, even if it's commented out.